# Not able to select item from autocomplete text in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete, cordova

I have created and autocomplete text using jquery mobile. I am able to fetch the data from the remote server but the problem is when I click on the list it only show that list is click what I want is when I select item from list the selected item should place in the input field and the list should hide. Can any one tell how to do this
thanks in advance.

```html
<input type="text" id="searchTermInput" placeholder="enter project name"/>
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"
    data-theme="b" data-mini="true"></ul>
```

Here is the coed for fetching the data from the remote server:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#searchTermInput').on('input',function(e){
    var $itemList=$('#autocomplete');
    $itemList.empty();
    var $inputElem=$(this);
    //triget only when at least 2 characters have been entered
     var keywords = $inputElem.val();
    if(keywords.length<2){
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:"link of the url file",
        type:"POST",
        data:{projectName:keywords},
        dataType:"json",
        context:{responseCallback: $itemList},
        timeout:3000,
        success:function(data,status,xhr){
            if(data.length>0){
                var listItemHtml="";
                $.each(data,function(i,val){
                    listItemHtml +="<li><a href='#'>"+val.project_name+"</a><?li>";
                });
                $('#autocomplete').html(listItemHtml);
                $('#autocomplete').listview("refresh");
            }
        }, error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what your problem is?

Comment: hey thanks for asking  i solved ma problem

Comment: @NeeravShah I am facing same issue. Can you please post the solution of this problem? thanks

Comment: Can you please post the answer?